# AutoMapper - Map two source collections of different types into a single destination collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have two collections on a source object of different types. I want to map both collections (a union of the two) to a single destination collection of a type that has all the members from both the source types. If I do this:

```
CreateMap<Company, CompanyResponse>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Owners, m => m.MapFrom(x => x.BusinessOwners))
                .ForMember(x => x.Owners, m => m.MapFrom(x => x.IndividualOwners));
```

It only maps the last mapping. I tried a more elaborate mapping but this appeared to break the entity framework projection integrations that automapper does. I am using ProjectTo.

This is what I tried which also does a good job of conveying the result I want.

```
    CreateMap<Company, CompanyResponse>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Owners, m => m.ResolveUsing(x => x.BusinessOwners.Select(o => new OwnerResponse
         {
             Type = UpdateRegistrationCommand.CompanyUpdate.OwnerType.Business,
             Address = o.Address,
             PercentageShareholding = o.Percentage,
             BusinessName = o.Name,
             BusinessNumber = o.Number
         })
        .Union(x.IndividualOwners.Select(o => new OwnerResponse
        {
            Type = UpdateRegistrationCommand.CompanyUpdate.OwnerType.Individual,
            Address = o.Address,
            PercentageShareholding = o.Percentage,
            Title = o.Title,
            FirstName = o.FirstName,
            MiddleNames = o.MiddleNames,
            LastName = o.LastName
        }))));
```

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [AutoMapper's documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#custom-type-conversion), you might want to try `ProjectUsing<>()` instead of `ResolveUsing<>()`.

Comment: Hi Erik. ProjectUsing appears to work on the entire map vs a single target expression. 
I can easily define a map from IndividualOwner to OwnerResponse as well as BusinessOwner to OwnerResponse. What I can't do is union the results of those two maps. I think I may just define two properties on the target of the same type for each collection. And then a 3rd readonly property which returns the combination of both. I run this stuff through a json serializer so I can exclude the original two properties and be left with pretty much the result i wanted.

Comment: Actually that approach didn't quite work. I still had to use ProjectUsing to control how linq to entities projected the business owners and individual owners and its working. So your answer was a help thanks.